# Как создать папку с текстовыми файлами в проекте и пользоваться ими?

Tags: c#, .net

Хочу добавить в проект несколько csv файлов и пользоваться ими, как текстовыми ресурсами. Ну и чтобы лежали вместе в папке для порядка. Создать папку проблем нет.

<kbd>контекстное меню проекта</kbd> ➙ <kbd>Добавить</kbd> ➙ <kbd>Создать папку</kbd>

Файлы тоже создаются

<kbd>контекстное меню папки</kbd> ➙ <kbd>Добавить</kbd> ➙ <kbd>Создать элемент</kbd> ➙ <kbd>элементы Visual C#</kbd> ➙ <kbd>Текстовый файл</kbd>

Но как пользоваться их содержимым?

Comment: Эм.. Предлагаешь закрыть как дубликат собственный вопрос? о_О И я не понял, при чём тут вообще ресурсы.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да свой собственный. Обнаружил, что есть дубликат. А с ресурсами уже всё в порядке ответы есть и тут и там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

После добавления ресурса необходимо задать в дизайнере свойство `Действия при сборке` значением `Внедренный ресурс` (именование в русифицированной Visual Studio, в англоязычной будут `Build Action` и `Embedded Resource`).
Для извлечения текстового файла понадобится использовать метод `GetManifestResourceStream()` класса `Assembly`, экземпляр которого соответствующий исполняемый сборке можно получить статическим методом `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. Не забудьте также что для использования `Assembly` нужно вписать `using System.Reflection` в заголовок модуля или обращаться к нему `System.Reflection.Assembly`.

`GetManifestResourceStream()` вернет `Stream`. Зная, что мы имеем дело с текстом, либо считываем `System.IO.StreamReader` весь файл в экземпляр `string`.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
...
public static string GetTextResource(string @namespace, string folder, string filename)
{
    using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
                                $"{@namespace}.{folder}.{filename}"))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }                 
    }            
}
```

Либо организуем другую логику считывания файла.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте механизм ресурсов.
Зайдите в свойства проекта, вкладка "Ресурсы", добавьте новый файл ресурсов (если его ещё нет), добавьте новый или существующий текстовый файл.
После этого можно обращаться к этому файлу как к `Properties.Resources.<Имя файла>`.
Т.е. если Вы добавили файл `main.csv`, то можно будет обратиться к его содержимому как к `Properties.Resources.main`. Это будет read-only строка с содержимым файла.

Comment: я хочу папку. Свалить все ресурсы в проекте в одну кучу Resources, это легко и удобно до поры до времени